# Recover data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to ask can the database be restored to an earlier stage.
Somebody logged into my system and run a delete command.
Can this be restored?

Comment: Probably not, but this question is off topic for StackOverflow. You should be asking on http://serverfault.com/ instead. Please see the FAQ for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I'm sure you have **backups**, right??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. Reload the database from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (if you are running in `Full Mode`) just reload information from the `Transaction Log`.

[How to: Restore a Transaction Log Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177446.aspx)

You might find this link also of some help:

[How to: Restore to a Point in Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982.aspx)

Comment: the transaction log is disabled. What should be done?

Comment: @user1057735: If you don't have a `transaction log`, then you will have to use a database backup.